# WPF - Cookie File being read but can't see it in assigned folder?

Tags: c#, wpf, cookies

I am making a WPF application, where a user logs in and it stores their token. After closing the application and re-opening it I fetch the token (stored as a cookie) if it exists in the folder directory I assigned and display it in a `MessageBox`.

However, when I manually look in the assigned directory with the 'Hidden Files' checkbox ticked I can't see it. Is my cookie being saved on my hard drive or is stored virtually in Visual Studio until I publish the project as an executable?

My Store Cookie Function is:

```
private void StoreToken(string token)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Value being stored in Cookie: " + token);
        Uri cookie = new Uri(@"C:\Program Files\WPFCookie");
        Application.SetCookie(cookie, (token + ";expires=Sat, 22-Sep-2018"));
    }
```

My Find Cookie Function is:

```
public string RequestToken()
    {
        try
        {
            Uri cookiePath = new Uri(@"C:\Program Files\WPFCookie");
            string response = Application.GetCookie(cookiePath);
            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            string response;
            response = "null";
            return response;
        }
    }
```

The Find Cookie method is called in my MainWindow method

```
 public MainWindow()
 {
        string cookie = requests.RequestToken();
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(cookie);
 }
```

What I don't understand is if I change the `cookiePath` in `RequestToken()` to a different path to that of which I stored it, it still returns the cookie which shouldn't be possible as I saved it to a different path. Also I can't seem to find the file anywhere. How is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cookie path is NOT the Location where the Cookie is saved! It is Kind of the Name of the Cookie...

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.application.setcookie?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Application_SetCookie_System_Uri_System_String_

> Persistent cookies are stored in the current Windows installation's
>   Temporary Internet Files folder until they expire, in which case they
>   are deleted. You can delete a persistent cookie from your application
>   by setting its expiry date to a date/time value that is in the past.

Comment: That makes sense! Are you able to tell me where the Temporary Internet Files Folder is located? I've tried following directories stated online but cannot seem to find it.

Comment: Should be <Systemdrive>:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache or open Control Panel - Internetoptions - Browser History - Settings - Show Files (here you can also change this folder)